# Three "elses" in "if" statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Is it possible to have an `if` statement with three `else` parts?

My login script checks the username, password and captcha. If the user/pass or captcha is wrong, the site return with an error saying "username or password incorrect". But I also want it to give an error when there are blank fields (just one is sufficient to give the error). I thought I could just add a third `else{` but Dreamweaver gives an error.

How can I achieve this?

```php
<?php
$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($result===1){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
    if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
    {
        header('location:admin.php');
        exit();
    }
    else{
        session_destroy();
        die(header("location:lgin.php?codeFailed=true&reason=code&user=$username"));
        exit();
    }
}
else{
    session_destroy();
    die(header("location:lgin.php?loginFailed=true&reason=login"));
    exit();
}
else{ //dreamweaver gives an error here
    session_destroy();
    die(header("location:lgin.php?blank=true&reason=blank"));
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: one `else` per `if`, as many `elseif` as you want

Comment: You may want to look at `switch()` statements. You can have one `else`/`if`

Comment: there are a few more issues with this code - raw passwords is a bag no-no and that `die` will not work, just issue the header then the `exit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only one else per if statement. If you are nesting `if` statement .. you can have more else .. but still one else block per if statement. As I see it , you have two if conditions and three else blocks. That will not work .. you will need to remove one last dangling else.

Also it will improve your code readability if you indent it properly.

```
    if ($result === 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        if (isset($_POST["captcha"]) && $_POST["captcha"] != "" && $_SESSION["code"] == $_POST["captcha"]) {
            header('location:admin.php');
            exit();
        } else {
            session_destroy();
            header("location:lgin.php?codeFailed=true&reason=code&user=$username")
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        header("location:lgin.php?loginFailed=true&reason=login")
        exit();
    }
```

You may want to use else if ... just in case you have more conditions to check. It will help if you visually draw a flowchart to see what you really want to achieve and then code it.

The code can be improved a lot .. but I guess that's not your primary concern here so I am leaving that .

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to use elseif, I just read on it but I don't know how to fit it into my code... And Dagon, don't worry, I will encrypt the passwords once I get past this mess.

Comment: If it's not false, it's true. If it's not true, it's false. It's one or the other, hence one else per if. PHP does not have an elseif, just "else if" - if (cond1) do_action1() else if (cond2) do_action2 () else if ... etc until finally ... else do_default_action (). If there are several simple conditions, consider the switch statement.